# ValueError: shapes (10,36) and (35,) not aligned: 36 (dim 1) != 35 (dim 0)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I need to know how can i predict the database , i have already train the model and i am using the same no of features too and still getting this error .

```
df=pd.read_csv('data_train.csv')
#df1=pd.read_excel('mailinglist.xlsx')
test=pd.read_csv('testing.csv')

test.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],inplace=True)

X = df.drop(['Avg_Sale_Amount'],axis='columns')
X.head(3)

y = df.Avg_Sale_Amount
y.head(3)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=10)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr_clf = LinearRegression()
lr_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
lr_clf.score(X_test,y_test)

predict=lr_clf.predict(test)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8bb70c9431d8> in <module>
----> 1 predict=lr_clf.predict(test)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    211             Returns predicted values.
    212         """
--> 213         return self._decision_function(X)
    214 
    215     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    196         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    197         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 198                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    199 
    200     def predict(self, X):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    171         return ret
    172     else:
--> 173         return np.dot(a, b)
    174 
    175 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (10,36) and (35,) not aligned: 36 (dim 1) != 35 (dim 0)
```

My prediction score is 0.8814429825462894.I need to predict testing file .
[Database link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UgzwUT-egc6R45C3AyRHsebQEr2gIYBV?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to drop `Avg_Sale_Amount`from `test`:

`test = test.drop(['Avg_Sale_Amount'],axis='columns')`

Comment: ya i just see.. thanx bro ,,

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your issue, please accept this answer as correct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work